# select a row that doesn't have a condition said

Tags: mysql

I know the title doesn't make sense, I don't know how to reworded it.
So here's what I'm facing right now. I have one table, a big one, it has almost 2M rows. This is the table and it already filtered by `NoRegis=1411940` and `Jumlah>0`

```
|| Kode || Nama || Kali || Hari || Resep || Jumlah ||
++======++======++======++======++=======++========++
||AL-128||SP 5  ||      ||      ||A      ||5.00    ||
||AL-132||SP 10 ||      ||      ||A      ||3.00    ||
||AL-132||SP 10 ||      ||      ||A      ||7.00    ||
||DS-074||PARACE||3     ||1     ||R      ||10.00   ||
||DS-119||ASP 81||1     ||1     ||R      ||5.00    ||
||AL-242||VEN 2 ||      ||      ||A      ||1.00    ||
||AL-242||VEN 2 ||      ||      ||R      ||1.00    ||
```

I want a result that only consist of data that has Resep='R'. Something like this:

```
|| Kode || Nama || Kali || Hari || Resep || Jumlah ||
++======++======++======++======++=======++========++
||DS-074||PARACE||3     ||1     ||R      ||10.00   ||
||DS-119||ASP 81||1     ||1     ||R      ||5.00    ||
```

see, the last data (AL-242) has two rows consist of both Resep='R' and Resep='A', I tried something simple like

```
SELECT Kode,Nama,Kali,Hari,Resep,sum(Jumlah) FROM Frm_Ranap 
where NoRegis=1411940 and Jumlah>0 and resep<>'A' GROUP by Kode
```

But I still got AL-242, which is not supposed to be there. I also tried something like

```
SELECT Kode,Nama,Kali,Hari,Resep,sum(Jumlah) FROM Frm_Ranap 
WHERE kode not in (
select Kode FROM Frm_Ranap WHERE NoRegis=1411940 and Jumlah>0 and Resep='A') 
and NoRegis=1411940 and Jumlah>0 GROUP by Kode
```

but every time I tried to run this query, it never show me any result and can't stop working, maybe because it has too much data.

Any sugestion?

Comment: One of your "AL-242" records **does** have `resep != 'A'` - the one that has R. Are you sure your expected output is correct?

Comment: yes, that's why I'm asking here, I don't know how to get the result like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's stick with the first query that returns.  You just need to move the condition on `A` to a `having` clause instead of a `where` clause:

```
SELECT Kode, Nama, Kali, Hari, Resep, sum(Jumlah)
FROM Frm_Ranap 
WHERE NoRegis = 1411940 and Jumlah > 0 
GROUP by Kode
HAVING sum(resep = 'A') = 0;
```

The `having` expression counts the number of rows in each group (i.e. for each `kode`) that match the condition.  The `= 0` specifies that there are no such rows in the group.

Comment: this is correct so far, but takes quite some time, is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: @student080705639 . . . My only suggestion is an index on `Frm_Ranap(NoRegis, Jumlah)`.

Answer (score 0):

You first select all rows that don't have what you want:

```
SELECT Kode FROM Frm_Ranap where resep<>'R' GROUP by Kode
```

Then you select the ones you want, but not the ones that are in the first select:

```
SELECT Kode,Nama,Kali,Hari,Resep,sum(Jumlah) FROM Frm_Ranap where NoRegis=1411940 and Jumlah>0 and Kode not in (SELECT Kode FROM Frm_Ranap where resep<>'R' GROUP by Kode) group by Jumlah
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think this might help you

```
SELECT Kode,Nama,Kali,Hari,Resep,sum(Jumlah) 
FROM Frm_Ranap 
WHERE NoRegis=1411940 
AND Jumlah>0 
AND resep<>'A' 
AND SUBSTRING(Kode, 1, 2) != 'AL'
GROUP by Kode
```

SUBSTRING(Kode, 1, 2) != 'AL' will filter the record which you want to eliminate

Comment: I am not sure whether OP is looking for the same query but after looking at the table it is a good way to take the desired results. Kudos!!

Comment: I haven't try this but isn't this supposed to eliminate all Kode that begin with 'AL'? I don't want that happen. the data I show you is just an example, thre's lot more, and I can't tell if I don't need all kode that begin with 'AL'

Comment: Yes it will eliminate all the Kode with 'AL'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` to select `kode` that doesn't have any `Resep` of type `A`. Generally, `not exists` is faster than `not in` when the subquery returns a large result set and the table is properly indexed.

```
select Kode,Nama,Kali,Hari,Resep,sum(Jumlah) 
from Frm_Ranap t1
where NoRegis=1411940 and Jumlah>0 and Resep <> 'A' 
and not exists (select 1 from Frm_Ranap t2
where t2.Kode = t1.Kode and t2.Resep = 'A'
and t2.NoRegis = 1411940 and t2.Jumlah > 0)
group by Kode
```

This query can take advantage of a composite index on `(NoRegis,Kode,Resep,Jumlah)`